# Enviar foto Api Rest nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, restful, amazon-aws

Estou desenvolvendo uma api restful com nodejs e mongodb. E estou criando um endpoint para cadastro de usuário, mas gostaria de enviar uma foto no momento do cadastro.

Qual das três soluções seria a melhor?

- Um amazon S3*, envio um base64 salvo no S3* retorno a url;
- Converto o base64 recebido e salvo no meu próprio server;
- Envio o base64 direto do device para o S3* e envio somente a url para minha api.

<sub>S3 = Amazon Simple Storage Service</sub>

Comment: Opinião pessoal: apesar de aparentemente esta pergunta cair na categoria de baseada em opiniões, acho que há questões técnicas que a tornam válida e portanto _não_ baseada em opiniões, mas sim em performance e _scalability_. Pode contudo ser ampla demais, uma vez que a resposta deve abordar configurações/serviços diferentes, `+1`

Comment: Olá Sergio, muito obrigado. Na verdade eu gostaria das duas coisas, performance e scalability, estou pensando em fazer algo tipo instagram(resumindo).